# Error on index page load. Issue with RouteConfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm getting an error during page load. Not sure if my RouteConfig.cs and Controller.cs need to be re-arranged. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
[image: Following is the error I'm getting:] 
[image: Following is my RouteConfig.cs:]
[image: Following is Project Properties:]
[image: index.cshtml]

Answer (score 3):

You should not access `/Home/Index.cshml` but `/Home/Index`.

Visual Studio has a behavior that if you hit F5 to launch the app while being inside a razor view, it'll open that razor view in the browser.

So in this case, maybe you did that and browser is trying to navigate to /Home/Index.cshtml which is not a valid combination of {controller}/{action} and thus you're getting the 404 response.

Also, in your **Web** Tab on the project properties, remove the `.cshtml` extension from the **Specific Page** text box.

Then please try http://localhost:60453/Home/Index or just http://localhost:60453. It should open on the home page and it should work ok.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Karel! After couple of trial and error, it actually worked out!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is in your RouteConfig file. Your default controller is 'HomeController' and it should be just 'Home'. By naming convention ASP.NET MVC adds automatically controller part.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.!

Answer (score 0):

In your RouteConfig, you don't need to point out "HomeController".Just write "Home" and it will understand it's a controller.After you did that, Home/Index will be your start page.
Start Action -> Specific Page means your project will start that page always,no matter what tab active on visual studio. I prefer to keep it "Current Page" selected.It's more useful to me.(Don't need to specify .cstml in there btw.)

Comment: Thanks Melih! It's working now after few trial and errors. I'm kind of new to ASP.NET MVC and really appreciate all of your help!

Comment: I'm glad if it was helpful.I am newbie on MVC also :) @Syed